# Iterating over a nested list and copying the values using list comprehensions

Tags: python, list, nested, list-comprehension

I have a problem trying to iterate over a nested list in python, and copy the values in the list into another nested list, adding one to each value as I go.

Say I have a list

```
input = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

My attempt to create the second list (call it `output`), was:

```
output = [[x + 1 for int(x)in y] for y in input]
```

This gave me the error

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

EDIT:

Thanks to the answers, the issue was trying to call int(x) - this was entirely unnecessary. Also it seemed to have no issue with me calling the list `input`

Comment: I think you're just after: `[[x + 1 for x in y] for y in input]` - not sure what you're trying to do with your `int` call - they're already `int`s...

Comment: It is generally helpful to include the full error traceback, rather than *"didn't work at all"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. `input` is a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input), so you shouldn't use it as a variable name;
2. There is a space missing before `in` in your inner list comprehension; and
3. You are trying to assign each value from `y` in turn to `int(x)`, hence the error message `can't assign to function call`.

The `int` call is unnecessary anyway, as your values are already integers.

Instead, try:

```
input_ = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
output = [[x + 1 for x in y] for y in input_]
```

Answer (score 1):

Move `int(x)` to the left side

```
output = [[int(x) + 1 for x in y] for y in input]
```

Actually, since `y` is already of type `int`, you don't have to call `int(x)` again, `[x + 1 for x in y]` would work fine

Comment: don't use input as a variable name either